# Using two GET variables in .htaccess (having problems outputting)

Tags: php, .htaccess, methods, url-rewriting, get

I'm currently trying to add a second get variable to an existing htaccess rule. I have little experience with the htaccess but using what expressions I know, I think it's missing one element to ensure the second variable is outputted correctly.

The domain (as the user sees it);

http://domain.com/london-area-info/?src=go

The rule i'm trying to apply;

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-area-info/(.*)$ regioncc.php?region=$1&src=$2
```

The resulting output URL;

http://domain.com/regioncc.php?region=london&src=

I appreciate I'm probably overlooking something but looking around I haven't found an explanation has to how to make sure the ?src=go is shown after the rewrite rule rather than in another directory like /xxx-area-info/src/ for example.

**EDIT**

I have  also tried the following rule but wasn't sure if I was escaping correctly

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-area-info/(\?src=?.*)?$ regioncc.php?region=$1&src=$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-area-info regioncc.php?region=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: This has done the trick! And yet I never even knew about {QUERY_STRING}, I'm going to go read up on it now.

Thank you very much

Comment: Since you are sending in values after `?` those get processed separately and stored in {QUERY_STRING} so you just need to add them back in to the resulting url.